# How to reset the command window size?

Tags: hyper-v

Has anyone figured out how to reset the command window size to its original? Somehow it's got itself mussed up and I'd like to get the default size back.

Here's where I'm at:

[image: Now]

And here's where I'm trying to get back to:

[image: Then]

This is an odd one. I've never seen it before. Google, the sum of human knowledge, isn't much help here I'm afraid.

Comment: I would use the mouse.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Well of course! Me too :-) But there's got to be a way to get it back to its default size, so a fella doesn't have to mouse around each time he signs in. Manually setting and then closing it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've changed the defaults then simply change them back. Right click the title bar, select `Defaults` and set the Window Size:Height to 25.

[image]

Comment: Bingo that's it. The simplest thing I never paid any mind to. Thanks! +1

Comment: Glad to help...